# How to build and install node.js on OSX from git clone

Tags: macos, node.js

I cloned the git repo for node.js

I checked out branch v0.4.11 (latest stable)

I built it (`./configure && make && sudo make install`)

Then I simply copied the binary alone to ~/local/node/bin/ which seems to work

I checked the versions (`node -v`) which correctly reports 0.4.11

But I don't know if this is the right thing to do, and if I am missing something from my installation process. It runs all my simple server scripts fine, but now I am trying to use NodObjC and am getting errors. I want to be confident that my node.js is installed correctly - and also to understand how it should be set up, what it requires etc... so that I can update it to whatever version I want, using a similar approach in the future.

So my question is... is it correct to simply copy the built binary to the ~/local/node/bin/ folder?

Comment: When you run `sudo make install`, it should copy the binaries to a system-wide folder that should already be in your $PATH. What kind of errors are you seeing with NodObjC?

Comment: when I run `sudo make install` it does not copy the binary to the folder in my path. If I delete the old `node` from my ~/local/node/bin (which is in my path) then no new binary falls in there, or anywhere. If I copy by hand, then it works for most stuff. I have never used NodObjC before, so don't know if it is set up right. The errors I get from the hello world in the readme is: `{ [Function: id] pointer: { allocated: 0, address: 4928189936 } }` and I get `Segmentation fault` from [this cocoa hello world gist](https://gist.github.com/1194032?_nid=14011577)

Comment: Hmm. I assumed you follow [these](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) or similar instructions? If so, it'd point to a NodObjC problem rather than a Node problem.

Comment: I solved the issue by completely removeing the previous node (the ~/local) folder, and re-installing from scratch - including all the modules and npm. It behaved itself when I did this, and copied binaries to the right place etc... I installed NodObjC twice (succeeded first time - but still got same error messages) and now it all works fine. I can make Cocoa Applications with JavaScript! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `sudo make install` should copy the `node` binary, but was not on my system. Solved by completely removing, then re-installing from scratch according to [these instructions](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation).

I had to install NodObjC twice - both times without error before I could use it.

All works now - Happy days...

- node v0.4.11
- npm v1.0.27
- NodObjC v0.0.7

Comment: Yes, I am glad you figured it out. Now go write some sweet Cocoa GUI apps with Node!